# Android ExpandableListView sliding children

Tags: android, expandablelistview, slide, children

I'm currently trying to develop an expandablelistview with two or more children per group.
It works fine, but now I want to animate a slide animation to the children, when the user clicks on the parent.

I found this library https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView and it works really well for one item per group. I tried to expand the xml layout file, so that I could use more items than only one per group. But it doesnt seem to work.

This is the original file. It includes two buttons in one row per group.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/expandable"
        android:background="#000000">


        <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Action A"
                android:textSize="12dip"/>


        <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonB"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Action B"
                android:textSize="12dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But when I now try to expand this layout, for example like this:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/expandable"
        android:background="#000000">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonA"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Action A"
                android:textSize="12dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonB"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Action B"
                android:textSize="12dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The "space" that is sliding down gets bigger, but I'm only able to see the first button. The place where the second button should be displayed is empty.

Has anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change parent layout orientation to vertical resolve your problem.

Comment: how could i be so stupid, such an simple mistake :D Thanks for your help, it works great!